# Regex for breaking the string inside and outside the quotes

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have to break the string in parts around quotes ('"') using Regex, I can use a string split like

```
// Split the string c using " as a delimiter        
string [] pieces = c.split('"');
```

but it would break the string around quotes and wont tell which part was in the quotes and which part was outside the quotes, I need to know that because I am handling both of them seperately. I need something like a combination of Regex.Match and Regex.Split.

Thank you

Sid

Comment: Please provide some example inputs and desired outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Again the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern to the rescue!

Cycle through the input with `"([^"]*(?:\\"[^"]*)*)"` and capture the first group.

- normal: `[^"]`
- special: `\\"`

And it will even take quoted double quotes, like in "a\"b", or even "\"", or even an empty string "".

(note that `(?:...)` is a non capturing group)

Comment: I think you mean `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` ([ref](http://books.google.com/books?id=NYEX-Q9evKoC&pg=PA264&dq=real+%E2%80%9Cunrolling-the-loop%E2%80%9D+pattern&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DyvxToPuM5SNigLb_ZzMDg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=real%20%E2%80%9Cunrolling-the-loop%E2%80%9D%20pattern&f=false)).  As a C# verbatim string, that would be `@"""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*"""`.  But this is only for *matching* a string literal; apparently, that's only part of what the OP wants to do.